# Sorting Dask dataframe with two fields

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dask

In this example I'm trying to sort a Dask dataframe using two columns, `balance` and `year` extracted from the `date` field. I'm attempting to concatenate into a new field the balance as string with the year as string, but get an error:

```
pdf = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
    'balance': [350, 340, 130, 280, 260],
    'date' : [datetime(2021,3,1), datetime(2021,2,7), datetime(2021,7,1),
              datetime(2021,2,6), datetime(2021,3,18)]
})

ddf = dd.from_pandas(pdf, npartitions=100) 

ddf['newIndex'] = str(ddf['balance']) + (ddf['date']).year   # <-- this throws the error

ddf = ddf.set_index(['newIndex'])
```

Error I get is:

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'year'

The date field is a Series, I get that, but how to extract the year from the date and concatenate the balance to sort by this new field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minor tweak will make this work:

```py
ddf['newIndex'] = ddf['balance'].astype('str')+ ddf['date'].dt.year.astype('str')
```

Note that the main error was in lack of `.dt` method and later you will want both columns as `str` to add them.

However, in terms of what you are trying to achieve it might be better to first partition the data on year and then do the sort within partitions. This of course depends on the specifics of your data.